# Tkinter: Fail to load button(command)

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-button

```
BoardValue = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
for i, b in enumerate(BoardValue):
    row = int(i/3)+1
    col = i%3
    btn = Button(root, text=b,padx=40, pady=20, command= lambda: button_click(i))
    btn.grid(row=row, column=col)
```

my code is as above

the command function is

```
def button_click(number):
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, number)
```

however, the error is the command argument.
when I press the button, I only get 9 which is not the corresponding output from the button.

i would like to ask how to resolve it while keeping the for loop.